# Turn javascript input into php-string

Tags: php, javascript

I found this script for making a preview somewhat similar to the one used here on stackoverflow. When users have typed in the post I would like it to be converted into a php-string even before being showed in preview. This will be in order to use the mysql_real_escape_string as well as other things.

How do I make it into a php-string before showing? And it would also be very nice to know how to make it show again after I have escaped the string.

It contains essentially contain these two parts of code

1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preview(field) {
        var p = document.getElementById('input_exercise');
        p.innerHTML = field.value;
    }

</script>
```

2

```
<textarea style="width:500px; height:150px;" onkeypress="preview(this);"></textarea>
<p id="input_exercise"></p>
```

Thanks

Comment: what does mysql_real_escape_string to do with preview? what is "php string" you are talking about?

Comment: what do you mean by php-string ?

Comment: If I understand you right, then this is not possible the way you want it. You could use an ajax request to the server containing the string, process it in PHP on the server, and respond with the modified string. This way you could "interleve" your JavaScript with PHP code.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_string.asp

I need to use mysql_real_escape_string since I want to save the post to my database, and I want the user to see what happens if he/she writes ', \, " or other things that will be changed. Also I want to apply other commands, that is what.

Comment: Nothing will happen if an user writes `'`, `"` etc. The data won't be changed by `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

I think There is a bit of a mixup. 
A lot of developers do not understand at first that javascript is rendered on client side, while the template ( in your case the php code ) is rendered in server side.

What does it mean?

It means that the server is running php code that outputs and HTML string to the browser.
This HTML string contains script segments with javascript.
Once the php code is done, the code leaves the server and travels through the network to the browser. Once it gets to the browser, the browser has no knowledge oh which code generated the HTML. It just as well could have been a static resource.

In order to run php code on user input, the user input must travel back to the server. 
And in order to show any code output to the user, the output must travel back from the server to the browser.

This round-trip is done in one of two ways. 
The first is forms, which refreshes the entire page ( not suitable for this case. ) 
The other is AJAX.

AJAX is a way to send small pieces of information to the server, render them on server side, and get them back after rendering into a javascript function. It's kind of like turning the textarea input to a "php string". 
What will actually happen is - you will send the text area input to the server, the server will render a php template ( in which it will simply operate the "mysql_real_escape_string" function on the data ) , the rendered result will get back to a javascript callback, and then you can please it in the "preview" div.

[Here a cool tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp) I found about ajax and php using jquery. ( use jquery )

Hope this helps.

The javaspcript code should look something like the following

```
$.ajax({ 'url' : '/render-string-for-preview', 
          'type':'post',
          'data' : { 'text' : $("textarea").val() },
          'success' : function(result) {  $("#input_excercise").html( result ) }
       });
```

And you should add a resource on "/render-string-for-preview" which will simply do something like ( not a php developer ... )

```
  <?  mysql_real_escape_string ( POST["text"]) ?>
```

And that's it....